# Is for...in loop inside shouldComponentUpdate() considered expensive?

Tags: reactjs, performance

I'm trying to implement `shouldComponentUpdate()` to improve my app's performance.

Normally, a component is re-rendered every time the user changes the value of an input field. Fields' values are stored like this:

```
{
  inputs: {
   fieldName1: {
     value: '',
     isInvalid: false
   }
   fieldName2: {
     value: '',
     isInvalid: false
   }
   fieldName3: {
     value: '',
     isInvalid: false
   }
  }
}
```

I don't want the component to get updated when the fields' values change. So I came up with this:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
  //The inputs object inside the state is passed down in form of a property called state

  const { state } = this.props;

  for (let key in state) {
    if (state[key].value !== nextProps.state[key].value) return false;
  }

  return true;
```

}

It works just fine, but I'm afraid that using `for...in` loop inside `shouldComponentUpdate()` might cause performance issues instead. Is it true? If so, what should I do as an alternative?

Thanks in advance

(In case anyone needs to look closely into this, please visit my repo: https://github.com/WebDeg-Brian/static-eagle-nest)

Comment: *"Is it true?"* Depends on how many iterations the loop has to make.

Comment: The number of field inputs varies in my application. So I'm really not sure about this @FelixKling

Comment: What do you thing will the maximum number of input fields be?

Comment: Currently it won't get pass 30 I believe @FelixKling

Comment: It's also true that users normally would fill the inputs in order, so the iteration wouldn't be a big deal for the first few fields @FelixKling

Comment: *"Currently it won't get pass 30"* Then don't worry about it. Look into it if you have > 500 fields.

Comment: Ok, sounds quite reasonable. You mind posting it as an actual answer? Or I'll do it myself @FelixKling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It works just fine, but I'm afraid that using `for...in` loop inside `shouldComponentUpdate()` might cause performance issues instead. Is it true?

That depends on the number of iterations of the loop. The more iterations there are, the more time is spent in the loop.

100 iterations will require less time than 10000 iterations.

There is no value in speculating about potential performance issues (expect as an exercise). Profile/measure your app and focus on improving the parts that are actually slow.

---

For fun, here are some measurements for iterating over objects of various sizes (ran in the Chrome developer tools):

```
var obj = {};
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) obj[i] = 'foo' + i;
console.time();
for (var p in obj) 'foo' === obj[p];
console.timeEnd();
// default: 0.01904296875ms

var obj = {};
for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) obj[i] = 'foo' + i;
console.time();
for (var p in obj) 'foo' === obj[p];
console.timeEnd();
//default: 0.465087890625ms

var obj = {};
for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++) obj[i] = 'foo' + i;
console.time();
for (var p in obj) 'foo' === obj[p];
console.timeEnd();
//default: 2.2109375ms

var obj = {};
for (var i = 0; i < 100000; i++) obj[i] = 'foo' + i;
console.time();
for (var p in obj) 'foo' === obj[p];
console.timeEnd();
// default: 21.291015625ms
```

But even the 21ms don't have to be a problem if other code in your app is much slower.